# Routing Class like Slim Framework

Tags: php, regex, frameworks, router, slim

I programmed a little CMS with Slim Framework for Routing.
Now, i wanna put all the code in my Routes in classes and joint the url by myself (without Slim)

I have a database table that contains routes like:

```
url: /app/user/list
URI: index.php?com=user&fnc=list
```

But i also want wo have routes like this in order to manage the routes dynamically:

```
url: /app/user/:id/profile
URI: index.php?com=user&func=profile&uid={id}
```

The Slim framework handles those routes with regular expressions. That's the way I want to deal with it too. But I am not so comfortable with regular expressions.

My idea is that I build a little Router class that joints the current url and searches in the database table to get the uri so that I can call the class (com) with its function (fnc). e.g. the profile function fetches the uid.

I unfortunately wasn't able to exclude the functions that are used in the slim framework. I even don't want to use other frameworks.

So my question: **Has anyone ever build a class I explained or are there any beginnings to extend?
Some Code would be nice too :D**

(I use Smarty Template Engine for rendering the specific tpl)

Comment: Urls like 

`/app/user/:name/:id/:whatever/profile.html` OR
`/app/user/:name/:id/:whatever/:id2.html` 

shall be possible too.
Just like Slim...

Answer (score 0):

Is it a training exercise, e.g. to prove to yourself you can do it?

You could (without using regex) split the request uri by the / character and then iterate in order through the array and use the same mechanism as ActiveRecord (from what I can remember), i.e.

1. read array item returned by the split function
2. if parameter matches a predefined controller (in your case class) use that class if not return an error or fall back to default controller
3. if parameter matches a method of the controller selected in 2, use that method if not return an error or fall back to default behaviour
4. if the rest of the array is not empty, use the remaining items as parameters for the method selected in 3
5. call the method with the parameters and return the result to the user.

One advantage is that you can use [reflection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) and [dynamic method (ahem functions) calls](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.funchand.php)...

That way you do not even need to have a database with all the possible uris (except maybe for whitelisting), you only have to check if the class (either via autoloading or via the filesystem using the Java Way: one class = one file) or method exists (via [method_exists](http://www.php.net/method_exists)) to fulfill the request or not.

I used that technique once for a web service prototype for a Flex based client: the guy building the flex client did not know beforehand the tables he needed and I was not available (read "assigned") to make a wrapper for each call he might need, so I ended up coding something that used oracle meta data to check if a table existed in the schema and then dynamically build a CRUD (crude, I know) wrapper around it in PHP :)